# EAK and ember-simple-auth custom authenticator

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to get a quick and dirty foundation for the authentication incorporated into an app using EAK.  The authenticate function works as expected: it looks for a matching email and resolves the promise if it finds one.

For some reason, the restore method is never being called on page reload...or at all.  I don't know if this is an issue with EAK, ESA, or something else I'm doing wrong.

```
var customAuthenticator =  Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({
    resourceName: 'user',
    identifierField: 'email',
    restore: function (data) {
        console.log('Attempt to restore -> ', data);
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(data);
        });
    },
    authenticate: function (credentials) {
        var self = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var idObject = {};
            idObject[self.identifierField] = credentials.identification;

            self.get('store').find(self.resourceName, idObject).then(function (user) {
                var dataId;
                if(user.get('content').length) {
                    dataId = user.get('content').objectAt(0).get('data').id;
                    resolve({userId: dataId});
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            });
        });
    },
    invalidate: function () {
        console.log('Attempt to invalidate');
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
        });
    }
});

export default {
    name: 'authentication',
    initialize: function (container, application) {
        Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen({
            user: function() {
                if (!Ember.isEmpty(this.get('userId'))) {
                    return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', +this.get('userId'));
                }
            }.property('userId')
        });
        container.register('authenticator:custom', customAuthenticator);
        container.injection('authenticator:custom', 'store', 'store:main');
        Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
    }
};
```

Any insights would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is the contents of local storage after initial authentication:

[image]

**Edit:** Shot of local scope after breakpoint

[image]

**Edit:** Added some debug lines to the restore method

```
restore: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var restoredContent      = _this.store.restore();
      var authenticatorFactory = restoredContent.authenticatorFactory;
      if (!!authenticatorFactory) {
        console.log('Log 1');
        delete restoredContent.authenticatorFactory;
        console.log('Log 2');
        _this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory).restore(restoredContent).then(function(content) {
          console.log('Log 3');
          _this.setup(authenticatorFactory, content);
          resolve();
        }, function() {
          _this.store.clear();
          reject();
        });
      } else {
        _this.store.clear();
        reject();
      }
    });
  },
```

The 'Log 3' line is never being reached.  I also tried manually doing the `_this.container.lookup('authenticator:custom')` which seemed to cause any lines beyond it not to be reached.  So it seems there is a problem with the lookup.

**Edit:** When the line `container.injection('authenticator:custom', 'store', 'store:main')` is removed from the initializer, the restore method gets called.  Obviously, without the store, the authenticator is not very useful, so a different method of handling that may be needed.

**And more:** It seems any injection to the authenticator is causing this issue, not just the injection of the store.

Comment: Can you check what's in the store (local storage) after the session is authenticated?

Comment: @marcoow I've added a shot of the store to the main post

Comment: can you set a breakpoint here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/ember-simple-auth/session.js#L215 and check what's happening?

Comment: @marcoow Well it seems the store still has the same KV pairs at that breakpoint (or the line after the breakpoint) and the authenticatorFactory and userId are present in the restoredContent object. I'll add a screen shot for safety's sake.

Comment: So does it call the authenticator's `restore` method then? Id `authenticatorFactory` is present it should actually.

Comment: @marcoow Nope. I have a breakpoint set as well as a console.log statement and neither are being triggered.

Comment: Can you debug a bit more and find out what it actually calls? Most interesting would be of course what the result of `_this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory)` is (should be your authenticator instance).

Comment: @marcoow Sure. Will report back.

Comment: @marcoow Updated the original post.  Seems like the lookup for the authenticator is causing a problem.

Comment: Further investigation reveals that the injection of the store into the authenticator is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was attempting to inject a dependency before I called the `Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application)`.  Here is the functioning initializer code:

```
export default {
name: 'authentication',
initialize: function (container, application) {
    Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen({
        user: function() {
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(this.get('userId'))) {
                return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', +this.get('userId'));
            }
        }.property('userId')
    });
    container.register('authenticator:custom', customAuthenticator);
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
    container.injection('authenticator:custom', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is register your custom authenticator **before** simple-auth.

Basically, in your exported object add `before: 'simple-auth'`